# Splitting string into 3 parts based on Space

Tags: oracle

I have a requirement to Split the data into 3 parts.

Here is the data:

Input:

[image]

Output:

[image]

I have written the following code and it works perfectly well, .I have around 50 mil + data in the table and takes lot of time to execute.

```
update  input_table
       set  FNAME = regexp_substr(Fullname, '[^ ]+', 1, 1) ,            
            Sname =  regexp_substr(Fullname, '[^ ]+', 1,2) ,       
            Lname =  case   When instr(Fullname,' ',1,3)<>0  then  substr(Fullname,instr(Fullname,' ',1,2)+1)
                 else '' end; 
commit;
```

Also, regexp_substr(Fullname, '[^ ]+', 1, 2) expects :

1. Space ' ' in the end of the string(without that the results get messed up)
2. Should not contain More than 1 space(my input data has more than 1 space sometimes).

I run the below query before I run the above Split Command , which adds on to execution time:

```
update input_table
set Fullname =upper(trim(regexp_replace(Fullname ,'\s+',' '))||' ')
;
commit;
```

Is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

regexp functions were very slow before Oracle 12. And even on Oracle 12+ they are slower then substr/instr functions, so it would be much faster to use substr/instr.
The only problem that you need to remove extra space characters in your strings, but there is very fast solution using `replace` function: `replace(replace(Fullname,'  ',' *'),'* ')`

Example:

```sql
with input_table(Fullname) as (
select * from table(ku$_vcnt(
'Test1',
'Test1 Test2',
'Test1 Test2 Test3',
'Test1   Test2   Test3',
'Test1 Test2 Test3 Test4 Test5',
'Test1   Test2   Test3 Test4 Test5'
))
)
select
Fullname,
trim(replace(replace(replace(Fullname,'  ',' *'),'* '),'*')) Fullname_2
from input_table;
```

Result:

```
FULLNAME                            FULLNAME_2
----------------------------------- -----------------------------------
Test1                               Test1
Test1 Test2                         Test1 Test2
Test1 Test2 Test3                   Test1 Test2 Test3
Test1   Test2   Test3               Test1 Test2 Test3
Test1 Test2 Test3 Test4 Test5       Test1 Test2 Test3 Test4 Test5
Test1   Test2   Test3 Test4 Test5   Test1 Test2 Test3 Test4 Test5

6 rows selected.
```

So now we can easily split Fullname by ' ':

```sql
with input_table(Fullname) as (
select * from table(ku$_vcnt(
'Test1',
'Test1 Test2',
'Test1 Test2 Test3',
'Test1   Test2   Test3',
'Test1 Test2 Test3 Test4 Test5',
'Test1   Test2   Test3 Test4 Test5'
))
)
select 
  v.*,
   substr(Fullname,1,instr(Fullname||' ',' ')) FNAME_substr,
   substr(Fullname,instr(Fullname,' ')+1,instr(Fullname||' ',' ',1,2)-instr(Fullname,' ')) SNAME_substr,
   substr(Fullname||'  ',instr(Fullname||'  ',' ',1,2)+1) LNAME_substr
from 
(
   select
      Fullname as Fullname_old,
      trim(replace(replace(replace(Fullname,'  ',' *'),'* '),'*')) as Fullname
   from input_table
) v;
```

Results:

```
FULLNAME_OLD                        FULLNAME                            FNAME_SUBS SNAME_SUBS LNAME_SUBSTR
----------------------------------- ----------------------------------- ---------- ---------- --------------------
Test1                               Test1                               Test1
Test1 Test2                         Test1 Test2                         Test1      Test2
Test1 Test2 Test3                   Test1 Test2 Test3                   Test1      Test2      Test3
Test1   Test2   Test3               Test1 Test2 Test3                   Test1      Test2      Test3
Test1 Test2 Test3 Test4 Test5       Test1 Test2 Test3 Test4 Test5       Test1      Test2      Test3 Test4 Test5
Test1   Test2   Test3 Test4 Test5   Test1 Test2 Test3 Test4 Test5       Test1      Test2      Test3 Test4 Test5

6 rows selected.
```

Example with `chr(0)` instead of `*`:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=802e9b10e8a1089b148afbd13e5ef2eb

```sql
with input_table(Fullname) as (
select * from table(ku$_vcnt(
'Test1',
'Test1 Test2',
'Test1 Test2 Test3',
'Test1   Test2   Test3',
'Test1 Test2 Test3 Test4 Test5',
'Test1  Test2   Test3 Test4 Test5',
'Test1   Test2     Test3   Test4 Test5',
'Test1    Test2     Test3   Test4 Test5'
))
)
select 
  v.*,
   substr(Fullname,1,instr(Fullname||' ',' ')) FNAME_substr,
   substr(Fullname,instr(Fullname,' ')+1,instr(Fullname||' ',' ',1,2)-instr(Fullname,' ')) SNAME_substr,
   substr(Fullname||'  ',instr(Fullname||'  ',' ',1,2)+1) LNAME_substr
from 
(
   select
      Fullname as Fullname_old,
      trim(replace(replace(replace(Fullname,'  ',' '||chr(0)),chr(0)||' '),chr(0))) as Fullname
   from input_table
) v;
```

Comment: @user2815115 you can't post your code in the comments - comments section breaks them. please post an example in the question or on pastebin or gist.github.com

Comment: @user2815115 ah, thanks, I have found the problem and fixed it. Please see updated answer

Comment: @user2815115 you can use `chr(0)` instead. Stricly speaking I used `*` just for more readability. chr(0) would be better

Comment: @user2815115 look at this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=802e9b10e8a1089b148afbd13e5ef2eb

Comment: Perfect ....It works fine now. Hope these many Instring/Substring will give better performance. I will test it with the full volume of the data . Thanks much

Comment: @user2815115 you can test it on generated data, for example: https://gist.github.com/xtender/36088d61ff56741b60fa9c970dc3dfb8

Comment: I tested the performance with using regex_substr(244 sec) and Substring/Instring(93 sec) .   yes your approach is much faster. Thanks Again